# bootstrap-sass 3.2 compass watch doesn't compile

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I have the following gems installed (on windows):

- sass 3.3.8 (maptastic maple)
- compass 1.0.0. alpha.19
- bootstrap-sass- 3.2.0.0

When I run this command:

```
compass create my-new-project -r bootstrap-sass --using bootstrap
```

The folder with my project does get created, but when I run `compass watch` on it I get this error:

```
WDM::Error on line [73] of c: Can't get the absolute path for the passed directory: '' !
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you're running `compass watch` while inside the same directory as config.rb?

Comment: that is correct, I just did the same thing again to double check and its still throwing me the same error

Answer (score 0):

you should run 
gem update

after them make a 
compass clean
compass watch

Run fine :)